# Your project contains issues that can be fixed by running "dart fix" from the command line

Tags: flutter, dart

I got below warning every time when I start project. How can I fix this warning ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6n9i4.png)

What is the reason for this error? How can I fix this?

My current dart version:Dart 3.1.3
I have problems with darts in all projects after working in this situation for a while.I did some research to solve this problem but couldn't find a solution

Answer (score 1):

> What is the reason for this error?

You can find out the reasons by running `dart fix --dry-run` to see the issues and the proposed changes without making the changes.

> How can I fix this?

If you are fine with the proposed changes, run `dart fix --apply` to fix the issues.

More info on `dart fix` command: https://dart.dev/tools/dart-fix